# How to avoid safari adding -apple-system-blue to my button

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm loading a website through an iFrame in my ionic app.

I realize that every button turned blue.

I've searched a little bit and I found that `safari` was adding the following code.

```css
button {
 color: -apple-system-blue;
}
select {
 color: -apple-system-blue;
}
```

How can I avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the [following thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690529) that gave me an answer to my question.

Basically apple is adding this color to every button and there is no way to avoid it.

So the only way to fix it is to add a color to your button.

```css
button {
  color: #000;
}
select {
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: It seems that also SELECT tag has the same behaviour

Comment: Thx @LucaDetomi, I've updated my Q&A to help others